# How to develop a function if you know the limits?

Tags: limits, functions

I know some properties of a function, but I don't know the function itself.

Is there a general way of discovering the function?

For example, I know that:

$$\lim_{ x\to \infty } f(x) = 1, \qquad \lim_{ x\to 1 } f(x) = 2, \qquad f(60) = 1.5.$$

I also know that $f'(x)$ is always negative (sloping downwards).

How might I go about finding out what $f(x)$ is?

Comment: The answer is that there are many that have those properties.  One possibility is that you have more information (maybe the function has to be a special type?).  Or maybe you aren't looking for some specific function, but any function that meets these properties would suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this information, it is not possible to identify the function. It could be any continuous, strictly monotone decreasing function, which attains the three values at $1$, $60$, $\infty$.

Maybe you want to restrict yourself to a smaller class of functions?

Comment: No, you're absolutely right, which is why I'm fishing for a general approach. I did stumble across f(x)= 1+1/x, but it doesn't pass through f(60)=1.5. I just don't want f(x) to grow too suddenly when approaching f(1) from the right. I don't care how it looks to the left of f(1)

Comment: You could try $1 + 1/x^\alpha$ for some $\alpha < 1$, e.g., $\alpha = 1/2$.

Comment: Your modified f(x) with some α<1 totally nailed it!  Thanks a lot. I honestly wasn't expecting to see it figured out so fast!